# Preimages of certain subgroups of $\bigwedge^{3} H $ under Johnson's homomorphism

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups

We have Johnson's homomorphism $\tau_{2}\colon \mathcal{I}_{g,1} \to \bigwedge^{3}H$, where $\mathcal{I}_{g,1}$ - is a Torelli group, i.e. it consists of all elements of a mapping class group that acts trivially on homology of a surface $\Sigma_{g,1}$, that is an oriented surface of genus g without a disk.  And $\tau_2$ is Johnson's homomorphism that was introduced by Johnson in "A survey of the Torelli group".

I'm interested in studying a preimage of certain subgroups of $\bigwedge^{3}H$. For example, let's consider a torus $T^2$ and fix two disks $D_{-}, D_{+}$, then we may take $g$ copies of a torus $T_{i}$ and glue $T_{i}$, $T_{i+1}$ pasting $D_{+}$ on $T_{i}$ to $D_{-}$ on $T_{i+1}$.So we have $V_1\#V_2\#...\#V_g$. Now we want to cut off some disk let's take $D_{-}$ on $V_{g}$, and that would be our surface with one boundary component. $x_i$ is a homology class of a longitude of $V_i$, and $y_{i}$ is a class of a meridian of $V_i$.

Now it's interesting to understand what is the preimage of a subgroup $W_{x}$ of $\bigwedge^{3}H$ that doesn't contain $x_{i}\wedge x_{j} \wedge x_{k}$ for all $i,j,k$. It's easy to see that we can add some BP-maps for certain curves to Johnoson's kernel, so we would get some subgroup $K$ (for example we may add just one BP map that's a preimage of $x_{1}\wedge y_{1}\wedge y_{2}$). I can't understand whether that would be enough to generate a preimage of $W_{x,y}$ (that's almost the same as $W_{x}$ but it also doesn't contain $y_{i}\wedge y_{j} \wedge y_{k}$ for all $i,j,k$).

Are there any useful tools for such problems?